# How to display the same scene in two ARSCNViews using ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am having trouble with my view controllers. I am attempting to create an app that uses ARKit to display on two AR scenes. I tried to use an outlet collection but I am getting errors that the value of type "[ARSCNView]?" has no member. I am starting out with Swift, so I don't know some things.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var bothEyes: [ARSCNView]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

        let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0.0))
        cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2)// in meters

        bothEyes.session.run(configuration)
        bothEyes.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to share a single `ARSession` between two `ARSCNViews` (and, as I said earlier, you need a delegate):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView2: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.isPlaying = true

        // SceneView2 Setup
        sceneView2.scene = scene
        sceneView2.showsStatistics = sceneView.showsStatistics

        // Now sceneView2 starts receiving updates
        sceneView2.isPlaying = true     
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
}
```

> But remember! Frame rate `60 fps` is now shared between two `ARSCNViews` (30 fps + 30 fps).

And I used `Horizontal Stack View` to arrange `ARSCNViews` linearly.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you clarify more? I don't really understand the delegate instances part. I also tried to get the view controller to inherit from ARSCNViewDelegate but now all the methods in the file are showing errors saying "Method does not override any method from its superclass" and "Value of type 'NSObject' has no member"

Comment: I want to watch it the way you do a virtual reality device. Two screens, same view (for now). I want to see if i can do that with ARKit. Sorry I didn’t explain what i wanted to do with it at first

Comment: Two ARViews, sorry about that

Comment: Hello @ARGeo, I need help with an issue I have. I get one screen Updating, but the other doesn't update. (Both cameras work). Can you help?

Comment: I am using an iPhone 7

Comment: Do you have `sceneView2.isPlaying = true` ?

Comment: I have the original code. Actually, it is sceneView that isn't working (the one on the left)/

Comment: Check the following project at https://github.com/hanleyweng/iOS-Stereoscopic-ARKit-Template